# javascript random number regenerate on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I have a var..

```
var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 8.8);
```

and I have a click function

```
$('.passShort').bind('click', function() {
     // do something here and get new random number
});
```

I'm trying to change the global random var not just inside this particular function.

Comment: Can we see how the first code block and the second one fit together?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I think that is what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `var` outside the function, but not inside it:

```
var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 8.8);
$('.passShort').bind('click', function() {
     random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 8.8);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to strictly define global variables when they need to be truly global, and I avoid repetitive code when possible:

```
setRandom();

$('.passShort').bind('click', setRandom);

function setRandom() { window.random = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 8.8 ); };
```

Setting the variable on the `window` object ensures it's truly global. You can refere to it as `random` anywhere and it will give you `window.random` but using `window.random` assures you are setting the value of the global `random` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you declared the `random` variable will determine it's scope. If you want to make it global, just declare it without the `var` keyword.

```
random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 8.8);
```

Really, it would nicer if you could combine the functionality you're looking for into some re-usable object, a Random Number Generator? An example might be:

```
var RNG = {      
  get randInt() { return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 8.8); },
  get randFloat() { return Math.random() * 8.8; },
  randRange: function(min, max) { 
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
  }
};

console.log(RNG.randInt);
console.log(RNG.randFloat);
console.log(RNG.randRange(5,10));

$('.passShort').bind('click', function() {
  console.log(RNG.randInt); // Whatever you want here.
});
```